# Question on Mahabaharta

Tags: scripture, mahabharata, vyasa, pandavas, itihasa

Dyuta Parva—Section 57—KMG

> Para 1—"King Yudhishthira the just having said this unto Vidura,
> commanded that preparations for his journey might be made without loss
> of time. And the next day, the king accompanied by his relatives and
> attendants and taking with him also **the women of the household with
> Draupadi in their midst**, set out for the capital of the Kurus.”

After reaching and meeting with all—Dhritrasthtra’s sons were also there!!

> Para 2— “And **those tigers among men**, having conversed with the ladies
> went through their daily physical exercises and then performed the
> religious rites of the day. And having finished their daily devotions,
> they decked their persons with sandal paste of the most fragrant kind.
> And desiring to secure good luck and prosperity they caused (by gifts)
> the Brahmanas to utter benedictions. And then eating food that was of
> the best taste they retired to their chambers for the night.
>
> Para 3—And those **bulls among the Kurus** then were put to sleep with
> music by **handsome females**. And obtaining from them what came in due
> succession, those subjugators of hostile towns passed with cheerful
> hearts that delightful night in pleasure and sport. And waked by the
> bards with sweet music, they rose from their beds, and having passed
> the night thus in happiness, they rose at dawn and having gone through
> the usual rites, they entered into the assembly house and were saluted
> by those that were ready there for gambling."
>
> “And waked by the bards with sweet music, they rose from their beds,
> and having passed the night thus in happiness, they rose at dawn and
> having gone through the usual rites, they entered into the assembly
> house and were saluted by those that were ready there for gambling."

——-Similar sort of paras are also in BORI CE edition.

My first question is who are “those tigers among men” & “those bulls among the Kurus” in the first and 2nd para respectively?

Both words, especially the bull among the Kurus have been used for both The Pandavas and Son of Dhritarashtra.

By looking at the 3rd Para it looks to me that the Above para was only for Pandavas—This is my interpretation.

My second question is if the words are only for Pandavas, then who are the females mentioned (in 2nd para) And women of the household (1st para )?--other than Draupadi and Shubhadra as they are mentioned

Answer (score 3):

Other than Draupadi and Subhadra, the women of the household probably refers to the other wives of Pandavas -

> "In a svayamvara,**Yudhishthira obtained Devika** as his wife. She was
> the daughter of Govasana of the Shibi lineage and through her he had a
> son named Youdheya. Through a viryashulka marriage, **Bhima obtained
> as his wife Baladhara**, the daughter of the king of Kashi. Through
> her, he had a son named Sarvaga. Arjuna went to Dvaravati and obtained
> Vasudeva’s sister Subhadra as his wife. Through her, he had a son
> named Abhimanyu. **Nakula had Karenumati from the Chedi region as his
> wife** and through her had a son named Niramitra. In a svayamvara,
> **Sahadeva obtained Vijaya, daughter  of the king of Madra**, as his wife and had a son named Suhotra."

90, Sambhava Parva, BORI Mahabharata

Comment: Thanks!! I will exclude Yudhisthira marrying Devika. Tha is very blurred. The Pandavas had other wives too. Bhima was married to Hidimba.
Arjuna was married to Subhadra, Ulupi and Chitrangada. Nakula was
married to Karenumati and Sahadeva to Vijaya---BORI CE Vana Parva!!